# Android: NPE in Activity onCreate caused by custom View saved state

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, state, fragment

I have a custom view that's being used inside a Fragment in my app that seems to be causing a null pointer exception if you multitask away from the app and let it sit a long time, then open the app back up. It's really hard to reproduce, but here's the stack trace:

> 10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.tablet/com.mycompany.activities.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: expected receiver of type
>   com.mycompany.views.CustomView$SavedState, not null 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   expected receiver of type
>   com.mycompany.views.CustomView$SavedState, not null 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Field.getField(Native Method) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:235) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1947) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1846) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2112) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1568) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1903) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:215) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1217) 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:681)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:926)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:909)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1574)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:869) 10-03 13:07:19.560:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   com.webtrends.mobile.android.WebtrendsActivity.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source) 10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   com.mycompany.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:173)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
>   10-03 13:07:19.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7723):     ... 11 more 10-03
>   13:07:19.560: WARN/ActivityManager(286):   Force finishing activity
>   com.mycompany.tablet/com.mycompany.activities.MainActivity 10-03
>   13:07:19.600: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7723): GC_CONCURRENT freed 238K, 5% free
>   6461K/6791K, paused 3ms+3ms 10-03 13:07:19.650:
>   INFO/SurfaceFlinger(223): id=1946 Removed RecentsPanel idx=5 Map
>   Size=4 10-03 13:07:19.650: ERROR/android.os.Debug(286): Dumpstate >
>   /data/log/dumpstate_app_error

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I can remember. It's been a while.

Comment: This has been unanswered for quite a long time.  I am also experiencing this problem  Very difficult to reproduce.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FragmentActivity NullPointer in onCreate savedInstanceState Bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151755/fragmentactivity-nullpointer-in-oncreate-savedinstancestate-bundle)