# can't pass Parcelable data between activities

Tags: android

I looked everywhere and I think I'm missing something... I trying to pass my ArrayList with my object from activity to activity and getting "Unable to start activity... null pointer exception expected receiver of type EcgResultsHolder"...and the app crashes.

the type:

```
    public class EcgDetails
{
    private final String m_EcgProperties;
    private final String m_Category;

    public EcgDetails(String i_EcgProps, String i_Category)
    {
        m_EcgProperties = i_EcgProps;
        m_Category = i_Category;
    }

    public String getEcgParams()
    {
        return m_EcgProperties;
    }

    public String getCategory()
    {
        return m_Category;
    }
}

public class EcgResultsHolder extends ArrayList<EcgDetails> implements Parcelable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 663585476779879096L;

    public EcgResultsHolder( )
    {

    }

    public EcgResultsHolder(Parcel in){
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        @Override
        public EcgResultsHolder createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new EcgResultsHolder(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] newArray(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

    };

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        this.clear();

        //First we have to read the list size
        int size = in.readInt();

        //Reading remember that we wrote first the Name and later the Phone Number.
        //Order is fundamental

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            EcgDetails c = new EcgDetails(in.readString(), in.readString());
            this.add(c);
        }

    }




    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) 
    {
        int size = this.size();
        //We have to write the list size, we need him recreating the list
        dest.writeInt(size);
        //We decided arbitrarily to write first the Name and later the Phone Number.
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            EcgDetails c = this.get(i);
            dest.writeString(c.getEcgParams());
            dest.writeString(c.getCategory());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }   

}
```

this is how I put it:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
        bundle.putParcelable("EcgList", m_EcgListFromServer);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

this is how I read it on the called activity:

```
EcgResultsHolder m_EcgList = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("EcgList");
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. If you cannot interpret the stack trace, paste the stack trace into your question.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, have you tried putting it in and getting it out of a `Bundle` without going through the intent and startActivity steps? That would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FragmentActivity NullPointer in onCreate savedInstanceState Bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151755/fragmentactivity-nullpointer-in-oncreate-savedinstancestate-bundle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **static** qualifier to your `CREATOR` field. It must be static.

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<EcgResultsHolder> CREATOR 
      = new Parcelable.Creator<EcgResultsHolder>() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I deleted the the static because I have the error:Multiple markers at this line
 - The field CREATOR cannot be declared static; static fields can only be declared in static or top level 
  types
 - Parcelable.Creator is a raw type. References to generic type Parcelable.Creator<T> should be 
  parameterized
 - Parcelable.Creator is a raw type. References to generic type Parcelable.Creator<T> should be 
  parameterized                                                 and the eclipse giving me the following options: to remove the static or make the whole calss static