# passing parcelable class from fragment to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I usually have no problem with parcelable, but this time i got NPE...and i cant fix it. Please kindly help me.

The NPE occurred **only** when i try to pass the parcelable class from fragment to another activity. Things working fine if i pass the parcelable class from activity to another activity or from activity to fragment.

This is my fragment code, the `child` (parcelable class) is NOT null when i debugged it :

```
if(v == imgChild)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailChildActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("child", child);
    startActivity(i);
    Log.d("menu", "children");
}
```

Here in my target `onCreate` activity :

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
if(data != null)
{
    child = data.getParcelable("child"); //NPE here

    txtName.setText(child.getName());
}
```

This is strange. The data is NOT null, but the parcelable is always null.

This is my parcelable (`Child`) class :

```
public final Parcelable.Creator<Child> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Child>() {
    public Child createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Child(in);
    }

    public Child[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Child[size];
    }
};

private Child(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    user_id = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    gender = in.readString();
    born_date = in.readString();
    born_hour = in.readString();
    hospital = in.readString();
    result = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeInt(user_id);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(gender);
    dest.writeString(born_date);
    dest.writeString(born_hour);
    dest.writeString(hospital);
    dest.writeString(result);
}
```

This is what the `log cat` said :

**expected receiver of type com.blabla.child, but got null**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post the full trace back and also the code that reads and writes the object to the parcel? thanks

Comment: @Fred sorry, what do u mean by "full trace"? I will post my read and write parcelable code, Thanks

Comment: so wait a second, is `Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();` null?

Comment: @Zhuinden no, the data is not nul. But the child object does.

Comment: Guys Thanks a lot, i have solved this. I will answer my own question shortly

Answer (score 1):

Strange. I know the answer, **but i dont understand why**. Its from [FragmentActivity NullPointer in onCreate savedInstanceState Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151755/fragmentactivity-nullpointer-in-oncreate-savedinstancestate-bundle) :

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator
```

The creator should be in static and final, not just final. Thats it.

Maybe you can explain to me how this work, this is the answer for now.